# Complex filtering by group in R

Tags: r, filter

I have the below dataframe in R:

```
tibble::tribble(
  ~row_num, ~draft_id, ~NFL_team, ~team_pos,
        1L,        1L,      "KC",     "WR1",
        2L,        1L,     "CIN",     "RB1",
        3L,        1L,     "DAL",     "WR2",
        4L,        1L,     "CAR",     "WR1",
        5L,        1L,      "LV",     "RB1",
        6L,        1L,     "DAL",     "QB1",
        7L,        1L,      "NE",     "RB1",
        8L,        1L,      "NO",     "WR1",
        9L,        1L,     "IND",     "WR1",
       10L,        1L,     "DEN",     "TE1",
       11L,        1L,     "BUF",     "RB2",
       12L,        1L,     "BUF",     "WR3",
       13L,        1L,      "NO",     "TE1",
       14L,        1L,     "ARI",     "WR3",
       15L,        1L,      "LV",     "QB1",
       16L,        1L,     "LAC",     "QB1",
       17L,        1L,     "IND",     "RB3",
       18L,        1L,     "NYJ",     "RB1",
       19L,        2L,     "DAL",     "RB1",
       20L,        2L,     "ARI",     "WR1",
       21L,        2L,     "SEA",     "WR1",
       22L,        2L,      "LA",     "RB1",
       23L,        2L,     "IND",     "WR2",
       24L,        2L,     "CLE",     "WR1",
       25L,        2L,      "LV",     "WR2",
       26L,        2L,     "CHI",     "TE1",
       27L,        2L,     "BUF",     "RB2",
       28L,        2L,     "MIA",     "WR2",
       29L,        2L,     "MIA",     "TE1",
       30L,        2L,      "SF",     "WR2",
       31L,        2L,     "LAC",     "RB3",
       32L,        2L,     "CLE",     "QB1",
       33L,        2L,      "LA",     "QB1",
       34L,        2L,     "MIA",     "RB2",
       35L,        2L,      "LV",     "QB1",
       36L,        2L,     "CLE",     "WR2"
  )
```

What I want to do is filter on draft teams (i.e., draft_id) that have, for example, the QB1 and WR2 in team_pos that are on the same NFL_team. So if I set my values to c("QB1", "WR2") it would filter on row_num 3 and 6 for draft_id 1 and row_num 25,32 , 35, and 36 for draft_id 2. Any suggestions on how to do this would be appreciated!

Comment: @akrun because draft_id 2 doesn't have the QB1 for IND

Comment: But, `LV` also have the same case i.e. `df1 %>% group_by(draft_id, NFL_team) %>% filter(all(c("QB1", "WR2") %in% team_pos), team_pos %in% c("QB1", "WR2")) %>% ungroup`

Comment: Can you tell about the logic of removing the rows with `LV` team

Comment: @akrun yes because I missed it :) sorry!

Answer (score 2):

We may use two logical expression in `filter` after grouping by 'draft_id' and 'NFL_team' - 1) check whether `all` the input vector values are there `%in%` the 'team_pos' column, 2) we create the condition with 'team_pos' on the lhs of `%in%`

```
library(dplyr)
team_vec <- c("QB1", "WR2") 
df1 %>% 
  group_by(draft_id, NFL_team) %>%
  filter(all(team_vec%in% team_pos), team_pos %in% team_vec) %>% 
  ungroup
```

The first logical expression, returns a single `TRUE/FALSE` because it is wrapped with `all`, thus removing any groups having only a subset of matches.  Combining this with the second expression make sure we get only those rows that matches the input vec as well as to get only those groups

Comment: That did the trick! Are you able to explain why that works?